# Postgres count unique result in GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have a table:

```
id | parent_id  |    create_time  
---|------------|--------------------  
1  |     1      | 2016-08-26 00:00:00  
2  |     2      | 2016-08-24 00:00:00  
3  |     2      | 2016-08-22 00:00:00  
4  |     4      | 2016-07-26 00:00:00  
5  |     5      | 2016-07-24 00:00:00
```

I need to count unique 'parent_id' for each month(week,day).
Output something like this:

```
---------------------|----  
2016-08-01 00:00:00  |  2  
2016-07-01 00:00:00  |  2
```

But I could only do so:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', create_time),count(parent_id) FROM test GROUP BY
date_trunc('month', create_time),parent_id
```

Result:

```
--------------------|---
2016-07-01 00:00:00 | 1
2016-07-01 00:00:00 | 1
2016-08-01 00:00:00 | 1
2016-08-01 00:00:00 | 2
```

I tried a lot of options, but do not have enough knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `parent_id` from the `group by` clause. And you probably want to use `count(distinct parent_id)` as well:

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', create_time),
       count(distinct parent_id) 
FROM test 
GROUP BY date_trunc('month', create_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
SELECT date_trunc('month', create_time),count(distinct parent_id) FROM test GROUP BY
date_trunc('month', create_time)
```